# Setting up pgRouting

Tags: pgrouting, postgis-2.0

I'm following anita Graser's process (https://anitagraser.com/2011/05/13/catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-driving_distance/) and I don't know how to add LANGUAGE C. When I try to execute  `routing_dd.sql` it says Language 'C' doesn't exist. I try the command `CREATE LANGUAGE 'C'` but it is not supported. How can I add this language?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to follow instructions from 2011. They don't apply to current versions of PostGIS/PgRouting.

Instead, just do

```
CREATE EXTENSION Postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
```

PgRouting should be shipped by default with current PostGIS versions.

See [pgRouting 2.0 for Windows quick guide](https://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/) in case you are using Windows.

Comment: You also need to do: CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;

Comment: I have added the two Extensions and the column 'source' and 'target' but when I try the command pgr_createTopology(), it fails and I can't move on with the instructions Can you helpme with this?

Comment: @RaúlIgnacioAránguizViveros that should be a new question. Make sure to include the command you complete sql statement in the question

Comment: @LR1234567 Thank you! I've updated my answer

Comment: @underdark I have created a new question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241761/problem-with-pgr-createtopology-in-qgis I hope you can help me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system are you using?

Try adding the language using a lower case 'c' instead - so `CREATE LANGUAGE 'c'` *[SOURCE](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/pgrouting-users-Language-C-not-found-tp5198592p5198596.html)*

You may also want to look into making sure you have your dependencies installed correctly using [this page](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/doc/src/installation/install-dependencies.html).